# How to fetch a data from two collections at a same time in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-shell

eg. I have two collections (i.e C1, C2) 
**both collections have same columns** (i.e _id, Message, Date) 
and I want to fetch only 50 documents from C1 and C2 in ascending order of date.

I am getting data from one collection only by using following query on `mongo shell`

```
db.C1.find({"date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2018-05-18T00:00:00.203+0000")}})
 .sort({ "date" : 1.0 }).limit(50);
```

but I want data from both collections.

Comment: to fetch data from other collection you need to make another find query. Or do you want to perform join in on two collections?

Comment: No, I can't perform join because for join i need to match columns which i don't have.

Comment: but I want data from both collections > Do you want to do it in a single query? or something else

Comment: yes @Astro , I want to do it in single query.

Comment: can you post how your output should look like? and one sample document from both collections?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two different queries to fetch data from two collections using find query:

```
db.C1.find({"date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2018-05-18T00:00:00.203+0000")}}) .sort({ "date" : 1.0 }).limit(50);

db.C2.find({"date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2018-05-18T00:00:00.203+0000")}}) .sort({ "date" : 1.0 }).limit(50);
```

You can alternatively consider using MongoDB's [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join data from two collections have a foreign field in another collection:

```
db.C1.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "C2",
         localField: "date",
         foreignField: "date",
         as: "C2_data"
       }
  }
])
```

Comment: one field should have be the same value to apply `$lookup`

Comment: $lookup will provide me left join concept which I don't want. I want 50 documents in ascending order from 2 collections.

Comment: eg. C1 is having { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe48b7d945612900a955cf"), 
    "message" : "ABCD", 
    "date" : "2018-05-18T03:29:59.460+0000"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe48b7d945612900a955d0"), 
    "message" : "EFGH", 
    "date" : "2018-05-18T03:29:59.461+0000"
}
C2 is having{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe48b7d945612900a955d1"), 
    "message" : "IJKL", 
    "date" : "2018-05-18T03:29:59.462+0000"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe48b7d945612900a955d2"), 
    "message" : "MNOP", 
    "date" : "2018-05-18T03:29:59.463+0000"
} *My O/P wl display all 4*

Comment: in that case you will have two make two queries to DB

Comment: if I'll get output from two queries then manually or through code I have to  marge both output and make it in ascending order and then display only latest 50 documents. which is not possible with bulk data.

Comment: you can consider storing this data in single collection and add key to differentiate between them. For example product_id: 1, product_id:2. Using this you can fetch required documents in a single query avoiding additional efforts in code and manual sorting